# how to setOnItemClickListener on listview and call the second activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I m raeding csv file and showin it using the  listview and  textview so i want set setOnItemClickListener on list view of text...and when i click on item then other activity will get open..so please tell how do i code for this..

Here is my code...

---

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //String listItem = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            String listItem = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(3);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), listItem.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Editinfo.class);
            intent.putExtra("spinner", chosenOption);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is catlog report..

---

12-08 11:17:28.630 20936-20936/com.technostark.com.myloginactivity W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108035a in package table 0 because it is not complex!

**Update**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android= "schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
    xmlns:tools= "schemas.android.com/tools";   
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/shape"> 
      <ListView android:id="@+id/editlistview" 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height= "wrap_content" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Here is textview xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/et_Studname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Student Name"
        android:textColorHint="#660000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#660000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="20" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what the issue you faced?

Comment: What is the problem here? You have called startActivity correctly. You should replace `.getItem(3)` with `.getItem(position)`, probably

Comment: when i click on any item it won't  open other activity

Comment: @cricket_007..Already i did it..but i m i facing same issue

Comment: Please show the logcat if you are getting errors. Note: `Editinfo` **needs** to be in the manifest

Comment: @cricket_007..yes i have Editinfo in manifest file..no error in catlog

Comment: `getApplicationContext()`...I guess you are inside an activity, so just use `YourActivity.this instead` . In the API it´s described : **This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component.** . But I guess this is not the cause, maybe it´s more a focus problem. Can you post your listView item xml?

Comment: @cricket_007<RelativeLayout xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools= "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shape">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/editlistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: 1) Comments are not intended for code. 2) I said *logcat*, not *layout*. If you are getting errors, then show it.

Comment: @cricket_007..i posted above catlog report..below is catlog report................12-08 11:17:28.630 20936-20936/com.technostark.com.myloginactivity W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108035a in package table 0 because it is not complex!

Comment: Its Log-Cat, not catlog. Anyways, that not an error, so I still don't know what your issue is. Please see about creating a [mcve]. We need to see what data you've set into this ListView. As I said, your code for starting the Activity looks fine. If you can't click an item in the list, then something else is a problem, not the code you've shown

Comment: okay...thanks for consideration

Comment: I don't know why you have `android:clickable="true"` on the TextView, but you should try removing that

Comment: cricket_007 is right....if an item in listView has `clickable=true`, the listener does not work. I don´t know why, but have seen this by myself. remove that and put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your TextView, give it a try.

Comment: @cricket_007...Like You said i made all correction but doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                TextView c = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating);


                TextView d = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);


                TextView e = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);


                //Toast.makeText(Video_Main_List.this,Config.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent launch = new Intent(Video_Main_List.this,Youtube_Player_Activity.class);

                launch.putExtra("c", c.getText().toString());
                launch.putExtra("d", d.getText().toString());
                launch.putExtra("e", e.getText().toString());
                startActivity(launch);

            }});


// you can also take value from listview items and send into second activity that i mansion above.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String listItem = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(3);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), listItem.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Editinfo.class);

            intent.putExtra("spinner", chosenOption);
            startActivity(intent);
   } 
});
```